# How do I find the market value of items in World of Warcraft?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Is there a way to know the prices of the items on World of Warcraft?

I have been looking into the action house before selling the item, but sometimes I have items that aren't being sold so I can't have the price reference, so I am not sure if I am selling them too cheap or too expensive.

How do I obtain item price data?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There's a few ways to do this. If you just want to quickly check snapshot of prices without regard for the economy of your particular server, just check [Wowhead](http://www.wowhead.com/item=58087).

[image: WoWhead screenshot]

Wowhead displays the items vendor value, as well as the average auction buyout price across *all* servers.

However, this information is sub-par in that not every servers economy is the same, and in fact substantial price swings occur across realms. Also, for items that are less frequently traded, there may be little to no data.

If you want a more detailed picture, you need to go to the source from which WoWhead derives it's average; [The Undermine Journal](http://theunderminejournal.com/) by contrast, provides a much more comprehensive picture, giving you price history and current pricing data for any item, specific to your realm and faction, as well as the cost of component materials for crafted items, should you wish to just produce them yourself or ask a friend to. Additionally, TUJ distributes an add-on that will allow you to view historic data for an item in game while browsing the AH.

[image: TUJ Screenshot]

As you can see from this screenshot, The Undermine Journal is far more detailed, as well as providing a more specific and accurate picture -  for instance, the item in question (Flask of the Winds again), is roughly 30% more expensive at the Ysera-Alliance auction house than Wowheads average across realms indicated.

([European players will note that TUJ EU site is found here](https://eu.theunderminejournal.com/).)

Comment: Of course, your server may have drastically different prices.  I played on two servers who had totally different economies at the same time before.  I kept feeling like I was underselling on the server with the lower economy.

Comment: @Powerlord: That's the whole point of Undermine Journal. It gives the prices *for your server*.

Answer (score 9):

Use [auctioneer](http://wow.curse.com/downloads/wow-addons/details/auctioneer.aspx) addon when you place item in auctionhouse for sale it will determine its reasonable value if no competition,and outprice if competition is found.(if youre new to addons you wont get banned or so for having it,and installation instructions can be found on the mentioned site).

Also you can check average price manually [here](http://thottbot.com/home) but it is far less accurate since values change depending of server an number of offers.

Comment: Auctioneer becomes increasingly more valuable with each trip to the AH. I'd suggest allowing auctioneer to scan the AH several times over a period of several days before selling. Also note that prices frequently change over the weekends (on my server, prices dropped  Friday - Sundayfor crafted items due to more competition from sellers, and increased for BoE drops due to higher competition from buyers).

Answer (score -2):

Beware of AH fees : a failed auction is (-15%x vendor price) per 12hrs AND when sold 5% is deducted from total amount of the sale.

For example:  selling a neck at 1.5X vendorSelling price equals that you can't do to many fails before the item is useless to sell at AH 15%+15%+15%+5%= (3 fail+1sold)=1.5 so those transactions were in vain because it is the same as selling it to a vendor in the first place. Ex.: 100g vendor=sold at AH 150g with 3 fail/1sold= 150g minus fees=100g.

Beware also that NPCvendor or PVP vendor will sale the same mog.
Beware that some mogs are ugly and will never sell.
Dumbass AH strats: Some players will sell bellow vendor selling price which is a loss considering that they will lose 5% value when the auction is sold.