# Vanilla epic mount value

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I have an old wow account with a oldschool epic mount(same skin as level 40 mounts).

This skin is not possible to get anymore.

Is it worth anything in in-game gold? It's not soul bound and can still be traded.

Comment: This is now a dupe of http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/26766/how-do-i-find-the-market-value-of-items-in-world-of-warcraft.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best chances of finding out it's value is checking the auction house of your server. If you can find an already existing auction you can decide whether you want more or less gold than the others who want to sell it.

If you cannot find it on your current server you can look up prices on [WoWuction](http://www.wowuction.com/) to get an estimation of the price. Of course this method can be used for every item to find out its value.

Generally Items that cannot be acquired anymore are obviously really rare and thus also very valuable so your chances of getting a good chunk of gold are pretty high.